# Most common bigram words distribution in a data

Tags: python, nlp, keyword

I got a dataset with utterances text column:

```
**utterance**
Where Arizona state located?
how to find Arizona state
is the united stated is the biggest country around the world?
Arizona state borders
united stated borders
```

I would like to get a bigram keyword distribution output:

```
  Arizona state 3
  United stated 2
```

This code is for unigram/one word:
`df.loc['utterances'].explode().value_counts()`

How can I do this for bigram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you don't want to perform any pre-process like lowering the characters easy implementation would be like the bellow:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
from functools import reduce
df = pd.DataFrame({'utterances':
                   ['Where Arizona state located?', 'how to find Arizona state', 'is the united stated is the biggest country around the world?', 'Arizona state borders', 'united stated borders']
                   })
df['bigrams'] = df['utterances'].apply(lambda item:Counter([bg for bg in zip(item.split(), item.split()[1:])]))
total = reduce(lambda a, b: a+b , df['bigrams'].to_list())
total.most_common()
```

output:

```
[(('Arizona', 'state'), 3),
 (('is', 'the'), 2),
 (('united', 'stated'), 2),
 (('Where', 'Arizona'), 1),
 (('state', 'located?'), 1),
 (('how', 'to'), 1),
 (('to', 'find'), 1),
 (('find', 'Arizona'), 1),
 (('the', 'united'), 1),
 (('stated', 'is'), 1),
 (('the', 'biggest'), 1),
 (('biggest', 'country'), 1),
 (('country', 'around'), 1),
 (('around', 'the'), 1),
 (('the', 'world?'), 1),
 (('state', 'borders'), 1),
 (('stated', 'borders'), 1)]
```

In case you want to add something more sophisticated, it needs to be done before counting bigrams. Adding trigrams and ... is easy then if you know :)

**UPDATE**

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
from functools import reduce
df = pd.DataFrame({'utterances':
                   ['Where Arizona state located?', 'how to find Arizona state', 'is the united stated is the biggest country around the world?', 'Arizona state borders', 'united stated borders']
                   })
df['bigrams'] = df['utterances'].apply(lambda item:Counter([bg for bg in zip(item.split(), item.split()[1:])]))
df['trigrams'] = df['utterances'].apply(lambda item:Counter([bg for bg in zip(item.split(), item.split()[1:], item.split()[2:])]))

total_bigram = reduce(lambda a, b: a+b , df['bigrams'].to_list())
total_trigram = reduce(lambda a, b: a+b , df['trigrams'].to_list())
print(total_bigram.most_common())
print(total_trigram.most_common())
```

Comment: Thank you so much, like you mentioned, I would like to make it more sophisticated with pre-processing. So actually I already tokenize and lemmatize the utterances with the use of spacy.load('en_core_web_sm'). And the result eventually is a new column "lexical words" which looks like: [where, arizona, state, locate], [find, arizona, state], etc.. if I apply your code to this column it get an error: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'. What can I do?

Comment: Apparently changing `item.split()`s to `item` would do the trick.

Comment: Worked perfect thank you sir. I tried to modify the code to produce trigram but failed. any idea how?

Comment: Please add what you've tried. This way issues can be spotted more easily.

Comment: df['trigram'] = df['lexical words'].apply(lambda item:Counter([tg for tg in zip(item, item[1:])]))               
                   trigram = reduce(lambda a, b, c: a+b+c , df['trigram'].to_list())

Comment: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'c'

Comment: I've added codes for 'trigrams' @Tal1992